# Nethereum: What is the relationship between Wallets and Accounts?

Tags: wallets, accounts, nethereum, .net

I am using Nethereum for .net.
I am reading this: https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/accounts/
I am also reading this: https://docs.nethereum.com/en/latest/Nethereum.Workbooks/docs/nethereum-managing-hdwallets/

An account is needed to sign off on transactions. Does every account have a wallet? Can an account have multiple wallets? What is the relationship between accounts and wallets?

Comment: the concept of "wallet" was created in the beginning of crypocurrency development and it was meant to make cryptos more friendly with the Users and pull more of them to use cryptocurrencies. So you might thing that wallet and account is something different, but it is the same thing. the word "account" is more descriptible and apropriate.

Comment: a hardware wallet is an account which private key is held on a hardware device, so it is not possible to hack it via network because there is no way to control the device remotley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

account is generated from public key.
public key is generated from private key.
private key = wallet.

so, all accounts are generated from wallets (private keys).

Comment: So one wallet can have multiple accounts?

Comment: "can have" is wrong to say because blockchain is not like register on web2. All private keys exists. a private key can generate multiple accounts (but these accounts also already exists). You generate an account based on nonce and public key => it is deterministic => all accounts already exists. If you want to "create" an account with a specific address based on right nonce you can create it

Comment: I got it. It's like an address or number. It's already there. It's just a matter of assigning it.

Comment: @Catalin a private key can't generate many accounts, a private key + address is what makes an account (+ balance and stuff to store other data of the account, like nonce for example, or code hash)

Comment: @Catalin What about client nodes such as Parity or Beth. Does every wallet or account have to be associated to a client node? My understanding is that the client node is the interaction to the exchange.